# MongoDB Aggregation by Date

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose, aggregation-framework

Here's how my collection looks...

```
{
  "_id" : ObjectId("53c66071409aeb38133c6ece"),
  "starttime" : ISODate("2014-07-15T11:22:25Z"),
  "product" : "1",
  "customer" : "Microsoft"
}
{
  "_id" : ObjectId("53c66071409aeb38133c6ecf"),
  "starttime" : ISODate("2014-07-15T11:22:25.882Z"),
  "customer" : "Microsoft",
}

{
  "_id" : ObjectId("53c66072409aeb38133c6ed0"),
  "starttime" : ISODate("2014-07-16T11:22:26.15Z"),
  "customer" : "Microsoft",
}

{
  "_id" : ObjectId("53c66072409aeb38133c6ed0"),
  "starttime" : ISODate("2014-07-16T11:22:27.15Z"),
  "customer" : "Apple",
}
```

I would like to group the data by date
and format the output so it shows like this... (I've put a comment on what I'm missing)

```
[
  {
    "_id": {
      "date": {
        "year": 2014,
        "month": 7,
        "day": 16
      }
    },
    "productions": [
      {
        "name": "Microsoft",
        "number": 1 //THIS IS MISSING AT THE MOMENT
      },
      {
        "name": "Apple",
        "number": 1 //THIS IS MISSING AT THE MOMENT
      }
    ],
    "total": 2
  },
  {
    "_id": {
      "date": {
        "year": 2014,
        "month": 7,
        "day": 15
      }
    },
    "productions": [
      {
        "name": "Microsoft",
        "number": 2 //THIS IS MISSING AT THE MOMENT
      }
    ],
    "total": 2
  }
]
```

I followed the answer given to question [groups by month and year using mongoose.js](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17062992/groups-by-month-and-year-using-mongoose-js)
and I'm fairly close to solving this but not quite there. I'm at the point now where I can't really see the wood for the trees!

Here's my code so far...

```
Job.aggregate({
            $project: {
                date: {
                    year: {
                        $year: "$starttime",
                    },
                    month: {
                        $month: "$starttime"
                    },
                    day: {
                        $dayOfMonth: "$starttime"
                    }
                },
                customer: "$customer",
            }
        }, {
            $group: {
                _id: {
                    date: {
                        year: "$date.year",
                        month: "$date.month",
                        day: "$date.day"
                    },
                },
                productions: {
                    $addToSet: {
                        name: "$customer",
                    },
                },
                total: {
                    $sum: 1
                }
            },
        },
        function(error, customers) {
            if (error) res.json(error);
            res.json(customers);
        })
```

The thing that's missing is the "productions number" total for each date. I just get the Date total.
Can someone tell me where I'm going wrong? I'd appreciate it very much. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To achieve what you want, you will need 2 `$group` phases in your aggregation pipeline.

```js
db.Job.aggregate([
    {"$project" : {"date":{"year":{"$year":"$starttime"},"month":{"$month":"$starttime"},"day":{"$dayOfMonth":"$starttime"}},"customer":"$customer"}}, 
    // Group by "customer" as well
    {"$group" : {
        "_id":{"date":{"year":"$date.year","month":"$date.month","day":"$date.day",customer:"$customer"}},
        "total":{"$sum":1}
    }}, 
    // Adding a $project phase just to simplify the JSON
    {"$project" : {year:"$_id.date.year", month:"$_id.date.month", day:"$_id.date.day", customer:"$_id.date.customer", total:"$total", _id:0}}, 
    // Second group phase to get the desired output
    {"$group" : {
        _id:{year:"$year", month:"$month", day:"$day"}, 
        productions:{$addToSet:{name:"$customer", number:"$total"}}, 
        total:{$sum:"$total"}
    }}
])
```

The above query produces the output:

```js
{
        "result" : [
                {
                        "_id" : {
                                "year" : 2014,
                                "month" : 7,
                                "day" : 15
                        },
                        "productions" : [
                                {
                                        "name" : "Microsoft",
                                        "number" : 2
                                }
                        ],
                        "total" : 2
                },
                {
                        "_id" : {
                                "year" : 2014,
                                "month" : 7,
                                "day" : 16
                        },
                        "productions" : [
                                {
                                        "name" : "Microsoft",
                                        "number" : 1
                                },
                                {
                                        "name" : "Apple",
                                        "number" : 1
                                }
                        ],
                        "total" : 2
                }
        ],
        "ok" : 1
}
```

To better understand what is happening, see the output of each phase of the pipeline.