# Group by date several variables

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mapreduce, mongodb-query, aggregation-framework

Using `mongodb` via `mongoose` in my `node.js` project.
My documents have the following structure:

```
{ created: new Date("2014-12-24"), last_visited: new Date("2014-12-24") },
{ created: new Date("2014-12-16"), last_visited: new Date("2014-12-24") },
{ created: new Date("2014-12-13"), last_visited: new Date("2014-12-13") },
{ created: new Date("2014-12-12"), last_visited: new Date("2014-12-20") },
{ created: new Date("2010-01-01"), last_visited: new Date("2014-12-20") }
```

I want to display how many documents were created/updated at certain date **in the last 30 days**. So the output should be like:

```
{ date: ISODate("2014-12-12"), created: 2, last_visited: 0 },
{ date: ISODate("2014-12-13"), created: 1, last_visited: 0 },
{ date: ISODate("2014-12-16"), created: 1, last_visited: 0 },
{ date: ISODate("2014-12-20"), created: 0, last_visited: 2 },
{ date: ISODate("2014-12-22"), created: 0, last_visited: 1 },
{ date: ISODate("2014-12-24"), created: 0, last_visited: 2 },
```

Notice that year 2010 entry was skipped due to it is older that 30 days.

How can I do that?

Comment: Can I just say that *"I have written dates that way to be short here"* is really a horrible way to present this. Should we really need to read all of your content to realize these are actually ISODate or really **BSON Date** objects? Why not use [**`$gt`**](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/query/gt/) from a date 30 days ago?

Comment: Not horrible at all, because some may think that dates are stored as text in DB and must somehow be converted to date format in the query.

Comment: No Horrible. A date like this is a "String". It's also not "lexical" which means range operators like **$gt** and **$lt** and cousins do not work. The additional **fact** is that a "String" takes **more storage** than a BSON Date, which is a "Long Integer" with "type" marker to show that it's a date. Dates are useful types when you mean to store that. Using anything else is mostly wrong.

Comment: to avoid any misunderstandings, I have converted dates to their ISODate form (without timezone and time part)

Comment: To *"Avoid any misunderstandings"* I have corrected your data to construct valid Date objects that will be stored in this format.

Comment: @Quest Im just curious is there any problem with the solution?

Comment: @Disposer yes, I was looking mongoose/aggregate kind of solution, something like this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17062992/groups-by-month-and-year-using-mongoose-js

Comment: as I know its not gonna solve with aggregation

Comment: @Disposer maybe it's possible to split the task then on 3 stages: get count by *created*, then get separate count for *last_visited*, then group (1) and (2) by date?

Answer (score 1):

A map reduce problem:

```
var old = new Date();
old.setDate(old.getDate()-30);

var filter = { created : {$gt : old}, last_visited : {$gt : old} };

var map = function()
{        
    emit(this.created, {created : 1, last_visited : 0 });      
    emit(this.last_visited, {created : 0, last_visited : 1 });    
}

var reduce = function(key, values)
{
    var out = {created : 0, last_visited : 0 };

    for(i in values)
    {
        var value  = values[i];
        if(value.created != 0)
        {
            out.created++;
        }
        else
        {
            out.last_visited++;
        }
    }

    return out;
}

db.runCommand(
               {
                 mapReduce: "test2",
                 map: map,
                 reduce: reduce,                
                 out: { "inline": 1 },
                 query: filter
               }
             ).results
```

Comment: Nailed it +1. But you should correct the "out" option which should not really be valid or a good example for other drivers.

Comment: what about part of the question where I want only last 30 days to be reflected? The solution doesn't seems to be used with mongoose.

Comment: @Quest It does not matter other than to use the **query** option on [mapReduce](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/command/mapReduce/) as I already mentioned. Also the "out" should be `{ "out": { "inline": 1 } }` or `{ "out": { "replace": "out" } }` as mentioned also. See ["out"](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/command/mapReduce/#out-options) options in the manual.

Comment: @Quest, I updated the map function, now it will skip the old ones

Comment: @Disposer Again that is good, but using the "query" option is better. You can code a "map" to "skip" items as you have in that revision, but "filtering" the input with the "query" is way better. Otherwise great to see this standard from fellow contributors.

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
db.users.aggregate([
    {$group: {
            "_id": {
                month: {$month: "$created"},
                day: {$dayOfMonth: "$created"},
                year: {$year: "$created"},
            },
            date: {$max: '$created'},
            created: {$sum: 1},
            last_visited: {$sum: 1},
        }},
        {$sort: {
            'date': -1
        }}
])
```

Thanks