# Mongoose aggregate output format

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I have the following pipeline in my aggregation:

```
$group: {
    _id: {
        $dateToString: {
            format: '%Y-%m-%d',
            date: '$created_at'
        }
    },
    num: {
        $sum: 1
    }
}
```

This returns me the sum of documents grouped by data, as such:

```
[
    {
        "_id": "2015-04-21",
        "num": 1871
    }
]
```

Now I would like to change the output to something like this:

```
[
    ["2015-04-21", 1871]
]
```

Is this doable within the aggregation pipeline? Or do I have to write my own transformation method?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the [**`$addToSet`**](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/addToSet/) and [**`$setUnion`**](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/setUnion/) operators in your pipeline as follows:

```
db.collection.aggregate([
    {
        "$group": {
            "_id": {
                "$dateToString": {
                    "format": "%Y-%m-%d",
                    "date": "$created_at"
                }
            },
            "num": {
                "$sum": 1
            }
        }
    },
    {
        "$group": {
            "_id": "$_id",
            "A": {
                "$addToSet": "$_id"
            },
            "B": {
                "$addToSet": "$num"
            }
        }
    },
    {
        "$project": {
            "_id": 0,
            "finalArray": {
                "$setUnion": [ "$A", "$B" ]
            }
        }
    }
]);
```

**Output**:

```
/* 0 */
{
    "result" : [ 
        {
            "finalArray" :  ["2015-04-21", 1871]
        }
    ],
    "ok" : 1
}
```

Comment: That is exactly what I wanted, pretty impressed by how much mongo can do.

Comment: @woutr_be Indeed, there's also the [**MapReduce**](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/core/map-reduce/) operation which does the same thing albeit slower since it uses native JavaScript functions for its map and reduce operations.

Comment: maybe this is a completely separate question, but let's say my schema looks like this: http://pastebin.com/3eMDkysM. Would it be possible to group it first by `searchId` and then by `created_at`? Something like this: http://pastebin.com/EYLBdDUA

Comment: @woutr_be It would be great if you could post that as a new question since it is quite interesting. Don't forget to include some sample documents and expected result in the question.

Comment: I'll just link to the answer that helped me solve this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17062992/groups-by-month-and-year-using-mongoose-js. Essentially using multiple groups allowed me to have that output.